# Laravel Eloquent eager loading multiple relationships to same model generates multiple queries

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship, translation

I am currently working on a project where translations are a core feature. Implementing this with Eloquent has been a great experience so far, but the problem unfolds when a model has multiple relations to one model.

Say you have a model called `Post`:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

// posts (
//    id
//    title
//    content
// )

class Post extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
   public function title() {
      // posts.title -> translations.reference
      return $this->hasMany('App\Translation', 'reference', 'title');
   }

   public function content() {
      // posts.content -> translations.reference
      return $this->hasMany('App\Translation', 'reference', 'content');
   }
}
```

And a `Translation` model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

// translations (
//    id
//    reference
//    language
//    value
// )

class Translation extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
   public function language() {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Language', 'id', 'language');
   }
}
```

And finally a `Language` model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

// languages (
//    id
//    code
//    name
// )

class Language extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model { }
```

Then the following will successfully generate the expected output:

```php
Post::with([
   'title.language',
   'content.language'
])->get();

[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":[
         {
            "id":68,
            "reference":"5efd07083a002",
            "language":{
               "id":1,
               "code":"en",
               "name":"English"
            },
            "value":"Title in english"
         }
      ],
      "content":[
         {
            "id":70,
            "reference":"5efd0708f1c82",
            "language":{
               "id":1,
               "code":"en",
               "name":"English"
            },
            "value":"Lorem in English"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Is that Eloquent sent *duplicate* (or *very* similar) queries to the database, making me wonder if there is a better solution:

```
[
   {
      "query":"select * from `translations` where `translations`.`reference` in (?)",
      "bindings":[
         "5efd07083a002"
      ],
      "time":186.14
   },
   {
      "query":"select * from `languages` where `languages`.`id` in (?, ?)",
      "bindings":[
         1,
         2
      ],
      "time":170.69
   },
   {
      "query":"select * from `translations` where `translations`.`reference` in (?)",
      "bindings":[
         "5efd0708f1c82"
      ],
      "time":171.93
   },
   {
      "query":"select * from `languages` where `languages`.`id` in (?, ?)",
      "bindings":[
         1,
         2
      ],
      "time":142.38
   }
]
```

After doing some research I could not find any answers to this problem except "it's not possible" with no explanation.

What is the best solution for this problem? Is there something that I am missing or is this really impossible?

Thankful for any answers!

Comment: You are calling on two distinct relationships (`title` and `content`), each of which then must call upon its own deeper relationship (`language`). That's 4 queries total for relationships.  If you want less queries, you will need to 1) reduce the number of Eloquent relationships being called upon, or 2) use the query builder to write your own more efficient (but potentially more difficult to maintain) query.

Comment: Okay, so there is no way to "combine" the to "identical" relations to use the same query? Currently, I am working around it by using my own queries to build the translation parts.

Comment: No, because your relations are not actually "identical" under the current configuration. Laravel sees 4 distinct relationships (1. `title`, 2. `content`, 3. `title.language`, 4. `content.language`).  If `title` and `content` were obtained from a single relationship (e.g., `translations`) then `translations.language` could be eager loaded and would only take two queries (1. `translations`, 2. `translations.language`), combining the now identical relations.  Being identical is defined by the relationship, not the model.